# Problems with excel application

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want an application that manipulates excel, I'm new to this so I started looking for examples. By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2013

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oXL As Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oRng As Excel.Range

    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXL.Visible = True

    ' Get a new workbook.
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
    oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet

    ' Add table headers going cell by cell.
    oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "First Name"
    oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Last Name"
    oSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Full Name"
    oSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Salary"

    ' Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
    With oSheet.Range("A1", "D1")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
    End With

    ' Create an array to set multiple values at once.
    Dim saNames(5, 2) As String
    saNames(0, 0) = "John"
    saNames(0, 1) = "Smith"
    saNames(1, 0) = "Tom"
    saNames(1, 1) = "Brown"
    saNames(2, 0) = "Sue"
    saNames(2, 1) = "Thomas"
    saNames(3, 0) = "Jane"

    saNames(3, 1) = "Jones"
    saNames(4, 0) = "Adam"
    saNames(4, 1) = "Johnson"

    ' Fill A2:B6 with an array of values (First and Last Names).
    oSheet.Range("A2", "B6").Value = saNames

    ' Fill C2:C6 with a relative formula (=A2 & " " & B2).
    oRng = oSheet.Range("C2", "C6")
    oRng.Formula = "=A2 & "" "" & B2"

    ' Fill D2:D6 with a formula(=RAND()*100000) and apply format.
    oRng = oSheet.Range("D2", "D6")
    oRng.Formula = "=RAND()*100000"
    oRng.NumberFormat = "$0.00"

    ' AutoFit columns A:D.
    oRng = oSheet.Range("A1", "D1")
    oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

    ' Manipulate a variable number of columns for Quarterly Sales Data.
    Call DisplayQuarterlySales(oSheet)

    ' Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
    ' of Excel's lifetime.
    oXL.Visible = True
    oXL.UserControl = True

    ' Make sure that you release object references.
    oRng = Nothing
    oSheet = Nothing
    oWB = Nothing
    oXL.Quit()
    oXL = Nothing

    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number)
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayQuarterlySales(ByVal oWS As Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim oResizeRange As Excel.Range
    Dim oChart As Excel.Chart
    Dim oSeries As Excel.Series
    Dim iNumQtrs As Integer
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim iRet As Integer


    ' Determine how many quarters to display data for.
    For iNumQtrs = 4 To 2 Step -1
        sMsg = "Enter sales data for" & Str(iNumQtrs) & " quarter(s)?"
        iRet = MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo Or vbQuestion _
           Or vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Quarterly Sales")
        If iRet = vbYes Then Exit For
    Next iNumQtrs

    ' Starting at E1, fill headers for the number of columns selected.
    oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E1", "E1").Resize(ColumnSize:=iNumQtrs)
    oResizeRange.Formula = "=""Q"" & COLUMN()-4 & CHAR(10) & ""Sales"""

    ' Change the Orientation and WrapText properties for the headers.
    oResizeRange.Orientation = 38
    oResizeRange.WrapText = True

    ' Fill the interior color of the headers.
    oResizeRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

    ' Fill the columns with a formula and apply a number format.
    oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E2", "E6").Resize(ColumnSize:=iNumQtrs)
    oResizeRange.Formula = "=RAND()*100"
    oResizeRange.NumberFormat = "$0.00"

    ' Apply borders to the Sales data and headers.
    oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E1", "E6").Resize(ColumnSize:=iNumQtrs)
    oResizeRange.Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin

    ' Add a Totals formula for the sales data and apply a border.
    oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E8", "E8").Resize(ColumnSize:=iNumQtrs)
    oResizeRange.Formula = "=SUM(E2:E6)"
    With oResizeRange.Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble
        .Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick
    End With

    ' Add a Chart for the selected data.
    oResizeRange = oWS.Range("E2:E6").Resize(ColumnSize:=iNumQtrs)
    oChart = oWS.Parent.Charts.Add
    With oChart
        .ChartWizard(oResizeRange, Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn, , Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns)
        oSeries = .SeriesCollection(1)
        oSeries.XValues = oWS.Range("A2", "A6")
        For iRet = 1 To iNumQtrs
            .SeriesCollection(iRet).Name = "=""Q" & Str(iRet) & """"
        Next iRet
        .Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, oWS.Name)
    End With

    ' Move the chart so as not to cover your data.
    With oWS.Shapes.Item("Chart 1")
        .Top = oWS.Rows(10).Top
        .Left = oWS.Columns(2).Left
    End With

    ' Free any references.
    oChart = Nothing
    oResizeRange = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the example I found in the microsoft support site, so I just want to try it before getting deep on topic, but I get these errors:

```
Error 1 'Visible' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.
    oXL.Visible = True
Error 2 'Workbooks' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
Error 3 'Visible' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.
    oXL.Visible = True
Error 4 'UserControl' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.
    oXL.UserControl = True
Error 5 'Quit' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'.
    oXL.Quit()
```

All the errors have to do with oXL, so I don't know if I need another import or something.

I must say I know NOTHING about excel applications, I'm about to get started on the topic and I'd really like to solve this, thank you.

Comment: I think the correct syntax is `Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` with the `Set` keyword

Comment: I noticed that, but when I write "Set" it automatically disappears, not exactly sure why

Comment: why are you late-binding Excel.Application?

Answer (score 1):

add these imports:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

and add the reference from the reference library:

- If you are automating Microsoft Office Excel 2007, the type library appears as Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library in the References list.
- If you are automating Microsoft Office Excel 2003, the type library appears as Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library in the References list.

find the one relating to 2013. You can't use the NEW keyword it is not allowed that's why it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you initialize the oXL object this way?

Try this:

```
Dim oXL As Application  
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

instead of `oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`